# react-native-fetch-blob is very slow

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

I am trying to read a file from the bundle assets on Android, and I noticed that it's taking a lot of time. The assets are XOR-encrypted PDF files (if anyone wants, I'm happy to provide them).

I cobbled together a bit of a benchmark using `react-native-fetch-blob@0.10.8`:

```js
import RNFetchBlob from "react-native-fetch-blob";
const { fs } = RNFetchBlob;

const t1 = performance.now();
fs.readFile(
    fs.asset("bundle-assets://" + filename),
    "ascii"
).then(data => {
    console.log(performance.now() - t1);
});
```

I ran this on a Nexus 5 running a development build of the app. All the tests were run while an `<ActivityIndicator />` was running in the foreground. Results are in milliseconds, as returned by `performance.now()`:

```
size      time (ms)

9.7 MB    crash and burn
4 MB      144132.19999999274  
3.2 MB    115553.40000000433    
1.6 MB    59854.999999995925
781 KB    28170.59999999765
78 KB     3373.600000006263
```

What could cause `react-native-fetch-blob` to take so much time?

Related [github issue](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/issues/102)